# How to use flint in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

So I haven't been able to find a way to use the flint other than laying it next to a pile of wood and hitting the flint with a sword. Is there a better way to light ? I would have thought it would be like cooking and there would be an action when you walk up to wood...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the intended way to use flint. I believe you must hit it with a metal weapon for it to generate a spark to light wood.

Answer (score 4):

Hitting a pile of wood with any fire weapon (sword, spear... includig fire arrows) will also start a bonfire.

Where to get a fire weapon:

> Top-right of the map theres a maze on an island you can reach flying. Going through one of the doors on the left will lead you to a bramble, once burned it down you can climb to a litle corridor where you will find a two-handed fire sword. There are a couple of Guardians at the start of the maze but you can easily avoid them.

I have the impression that theoretically it would be possible to start a fire with a lightning, but those come together with rain what makes impossible to set fire to anything.

Although it seems too obvious I have to say that you can light a fire bringing it from another one with a torch or a wooden weapon/arrow/shield.

As you said, flint is used to set fire, you can create your own bonfire hitting the flint with an iron weapon, light a food rack or set fire to a whole field of grass. Keep in mind that in bonfires you can still cook basic ingredients such as meat. It's also useful to make the time pass and to get warm in cold zones like high mountains or to melt ice.

Flint altogether with other materials can be used to improve some armors or forge some weapons. (Need to check this for more precise information)

There's also a guy in a horse house (sorry for the poor translation) close to the Orni town who will give you a reward in exchange for 52 flints. (Will improve this part of the answer once I can put my hands on the game)

Comment: I want to try and use my lightning wand/rod thing to start a fire.  I never thought of trying that before.

Comment: @JMac I don't think it's possible to do with a lightning wand. For some reason natural lightnings might work differently, since those leave a burning mark on the floor which doesn't happen with lightning wands. Worth to test though.

Comment: @JMac there is technically a way to control where lightning hits during a storm... at a price.  If you want it to hit a spot, equip as much metal weapons and armor as you can and stand in the spot you want it to strike, then wait.  It helps if you have fairies or beat the Zora divine beast so you can survive getting struck.  The ground around you will briefly be on fire after that.

Comment: There is one other way to start a fire: set red chuchu jelly down next to some wood then strike the red chuchu jelly. You'll want to put some distance between you and the jelly because it does a small explosion, but you can strike it with an arrow.

Comment: @Cody - You can do this without getting yourself zapped. Just drop a metal piece of equipment in the spot you want the lightning to strike. It will start to spark, and after a few seconds, lightning will strike it. I don't think the weapon is destroyed by this, though it may get knocked far away. This also might affect durability but I didn't test that far.