# In what ways can I make a fire to sit by?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Alright so I want to camp out in a certain area and wait for something I'm pretty sure only happens at night. So how do I make a fire to sit by?

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my wood bundles and my flint, but I dropped my wood on the ground and can't figure out how to use flint to create a fire in the wood.

What are the ways that I can start a fire (to sit by/pass time at) at whatever my current location is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use flint in Breath of the Wild?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303356/how-to-use-flint-in-breath-of-the-wild)

Comment: There is only one way to make a fire? The linked question simply asks how to use flint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fair point in your comment.

The ways that come to mind which will light a campfire, cooking fire, or pile of Wood are:

1. Flint dropped on the ground, then struck with a metal weapon.
2. Torch, or other wooden weapon, lit from another fire source.
3. Fire weapon strike.
4. Fire rod attack.
5. Arrow lit on fire.
6. Fire Arrow.
7. Explosive barrel.
8. Lightning strike, which will target a metal weapon or shield, or Link if he has metal weapons or shield equipped.
9. Fire-based attack from a monster.

Comment: Hmm the lightning strike thing sounds fun, since you could drop a metal weapon near a wood bundle in a lightning storm and it would light it. only issue is that the rain would put it out pretty quickly I would think

Comment: @GarrettJ That is true, unless you manage to be sheltered from the rain but still able to coax a lightning strike.